# GCM notification to iOS from Java server

Tags: java, firebase, server, google-cloud-messaging

I'm using GCM to send notifications to users of Android app from Java server using  `com.google.android.gcm.server.Sender` package. Everything goes well.

I need now to send same notifications to `iOS` users also.

I imported the project into `Firebase`.
I configured Firebase and iOS app (sandbox mode).

I registered my device on the new Firebase project.

Once I send message to my iOS device from Java server everything seems ok

```
result = MulticastResult(multicast_id=7691595883375589205,total=1,success=1,failure=0,canonical_ids=0,results: [[ messageId=0:1477921086188844%332d2a839f159410 ]]
```

but the message is not received on the iOS smartphone.

What is missing ?

Comment: Are you using a `notification` payload? Can you post a sample payload structure? Try setting the `priority` parameter to `high`.

Comment: @user1615181 I'm using the following code
`sender = new Sender(SENDER_ID);    

Message message = new Message.Builder()    
 .collapseKey(part1).timeToLive(36000)  
 .delayWhileIdle(false).addData("message", "text")  
 .build();  

try {  
 MulticastResult result = sender.send(message,  
 androidTargets, 1);  
       
 Debug.fileLog(logFile, result.toString());`

Comment: @user1615181  any `notification payload` .. just the text message

Comment: From how I understand the code, you're using a `data` message. Use a `notification` message in your payload for iOS.

Comment: @AL. yes, thus the question is how to send `notification` message from Java server. I tried to send JSON object to `https://gcm-http.googleapis.com/gcm/send`.. I see the correct result `result........{"multicast_id":8272152059347473050,"success":1,"failure":0,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"message_id":"0:1477933356128852%332d2a83f9fd7ecd"}]}
disconnect`  but messages do not arrives on app

Comment: Did you solve it?